# the microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following program in which i want to insert the values in MS-Access.I am getting the error "the microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine"

I have already installed the database engine as per suggestion of some developers, still i am getting the error.

I am writing the code on Vista machine with VS-2008 and MS-Access-2007.

Please help me to resolve the error

public partial class Form1 : Form

```
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    OleDbConnection con;
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
             con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Satish\\Documents\\Testing.accdb");
            con.Open();
            string cmdText = "Insert Into UserDetail (UsrName,Age,Address,MobileNo) Values ('" + txtName.Text.ToString().Trim() + "','" + txtAge.Text.ToString().Trim() + "','" + txtAddress.Text.ToString().Trim() + "','" + txtMobile.Text.ToString().Trim() + "')";
             cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the advanced compile configuration to x86.
This is usually because you have a 64bit operating system.

in VS2008

Build -> Configuration Manager -> Active Solution Platform: -> New -> Type or select the new platform -> x86 - > OK

**edit:**

Try the following:

go to

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

open `odbcad32.exe`

if you cannot find excel in the list just click on Add and add it

Answer (score 0):

You can register you assembly with `RegSrv32`

Because you use `COM`, and COM must be regsitered.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859484.aspx

RegSrv32 permit you to register your COM in register base (microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider)

Comment: I have already done these things, but still getting the error.

Comment: which file i have to register?

Comment: microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before when I have deployed an application on a User's machine that has Office 2003 installed rather than Office 2007. It sounds to me like the version of Office on your machine isn't installed correctly.

One possible work around is to change your Provider to a previous version like Microsoft.ace.oledb.4.0 and see if the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to check is your build configuration of your application.

- If you have **built your project under x86 platform**, then in order to
  resolve you issue you should install the following packages on your
  machine:

  1. In order to use the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider you must
     **install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable**
     first, this installation is available at:
     http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255 .

     After the installation has complete, try running you application, if this
     solves the issue great, if not, continue to step 2.
  2. This next step is an unexplained workaround, which works for Office
     2010, even though it is the Data Connectivity Components of Office 2007.  I am not quite sure why this works, but it does and this has been proven to work in almost all cases. You need to **install the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components**, this installation is available at:
     http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 .

     After this installation is complete, try running your application, this should resolve the issue.
- If you are trying to run an **application built under x64 or AnyCPU
  platform**, I would recommend first validating that it runs as expected
  under the x86 platform.  In the event that it does not run under that
  x86 platform, perform the steps in the first part and validate that
  it runs as expected.

  I did read that the MS Access drivers including the OLEDB Database
  driver works only under the x86 platform and is incompatible under
  the x64 or AnyCPU platform.  But this appears to be untrue. I
  validated my application was running when building x86, then I
  installed the Access Database Engine using the passive flag.

  1. First download the file locally You can download the installation
     here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
  2. Installing using the command prompt with the '/passive' flag.   **In
     the command prompt run the following command:
     'AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive'**

  After these 2 steps I managed to run my application after building in
  x64 or AnyCPU build configuration.  This appeared to solve my issue.

Note: The order of the steps seems to make a difference, so please follow accordingly.